# OpenLDAP configuraion in Yast2 - groupOfUniqueNames/uniqueMember

Tags: configuration, openldap, opensuse

in /etc/openldap/slapd.conf I have this acl and works:

```
access to dn.subtree="ou=users,dc=domain"
    by group/groupofuniquenames/uniquemember="cn=partner,ou=groups,dc=domain" write
    by users read
```

When I want to configure it in OpenSuSE 11.1 Yast2 LDAP server configuration it generates me file /etc/openldap/slap.d/cn=config/olcDatabase={1}bdb.ldif whit acl:

```
olcAccess: {3}to dn.subtree="ou=users,dc=domain" by  group="cn=partner,ou=groups,dc=domain" manage
```

How can i set it from "by group" to "by group/groupofuniquenames/uniquemember" like in slapd.conf?

thanks,
Al

Answer (score 0):

Got it! I have changed by group clauseto by group/groupofuniquenames/uniquemember in that file olcDatabase={1}bdb.ldif
Server must be started from yast2 (service ldap restart does not work even withou this change - it's strange!)
Yast2 configuration is then disabled because yast ldap module don't know group/groupofuniquenames/uniquemember access control rule. But LDAP works correctly.

bye